# How to insert a line break in chart Y-axis custom labels in Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

Is there any way to create a custom number format that includes a line break for chart Y-axis labels in Excel 2013? The zero-label in my chart is very wide and I would prefer that it broke over two lines.

I've tried Ctrl + J, Alt + 10, Ctrl + Enter, Shift + Enter, no luck. In the example below the format code is: `[<>0]General; "Index 21 Dec 2013=100"`

How it is now:

[image: Current chart]

And how I would like it to look:

[image: result]

Comment: Try `Ctrl+Enter`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but that didn't work either, have amended q

Comment: <shift>+<enter>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your long label with "0". Then insert a text box in the chart area that contains the desired text. To conceal the "0", make sure that your text box has a solid white fill and place it over the "0".

In Excel 2016, you can use the format axis menu. Format axis > text options > text box. There you can format the text box that contains the label, incl. set line breaks

Comment: This is how I generated the image for my desired outcome above. It seems there is no way to have a line break character inside excel's text formatting options as they are fairly limited.